# Foreign key part of a composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design

I have a table `Room` with primkey on column `room_id` and another table `Items` with primkey `item_id`. Each Item has a foreign integer key to room_id. When my program runs, it only looks at items in a single room so it would help if my primary key was on (room_id, item_id) in this order so that data is sorted on disk in this order.

Is this possible? Or do I need to duplicate `room_id` in `Item` and not have it as foreign key?

Comment: Why not just build a nonclustered index on room_id (that will contains item_id as this is the pk) ?

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher Because clustering is exactly what I want. I want my items clustered based on room_id

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point... The Clustered index is usually on the primary key (even if it's not required). You can put your clustered index on room_id and item_id but if ever you join you item table to another table, full table scan will be required and this may affect performance. Having a nonclustered index that only contains 2 integer field will not required a lot of extra space and will probably give you the performance improvment you are looking for. When I asked "why not a nonclustered index", I was expecting some technical reasons why you prefer to have them in the clustered index

Comment: Why did you tag your post with both sql server and postgresql?

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher My code accesses items in a single room. If I cluster based on (room_id, item_id) then all item_ids for the same room will be located in adjacent disk locations so seek times will be minimal.

Comment: hoooo I see... Your data is on a local physical disk on your SQL Server (not in a SAN) ?then... I guess you should do some test.. usually, having the data in line on a disk is far from giving huge performance improvment. I do understand you app access data for a specific room but who know if you won't have report or other feature later on that will need to read many item and join them on some other table. If you create a non-clustered index, the data will be order by class_id then item_id as you want them...

Comment: The clustering key is included in nonclustered indexes. So, if you build a nonclustered on `Items (room_id)` it will create a minimal structure like the one you're suggesting.
There are caveats though - like, you'll probably get key lookups to columns not covered by the index - but you should get into more detail for that.
Also...that data need to be cached by the database server - why care that much about disk IO if you can safely cache the data?

Answer (score 1):

Your clustered index almost certainly should include `RoomId` for the reasons you correctly identify: it provides an efficient access path to all records for a given `Room`.

But there are other motivations are well.  If `Item` is a child of `Room`, then you probably have an identifying relationship like `Room contains zero to many items`.

This would naturally lead your primary key to be something like `(RoomId,<columns that determine a unique item>)`.  So that *could be* `(RoomId,ItemId)`assuming that `ItemId` has some value beyond being a row pointer.

Otherwise it could be `(RoomId,SerialNumber)` or `(RoomId,ItemType)` - the exact answer depends on the data you're trying to store.

Answer (score 0):

Do Items move around or stay in the same Room forever?

If they move around and [room_id] is the first key column on your clustered index then you're going to end up with a high amount of physical fragmentation and maintenance overhead.

I'd recomend just Clustering on item_id and using room_id on a nonclustered index, perhaps with covering columns to satisfy your application's needs.

How big are the rooms? are we talking end scene of Raiders of the Lost Ark? If the rooms don't hold a lot of items then a Key Lookup is Good. On small datasets a Nested Loop is the fastest Join.

I am assuming that item_id and room_id are not GUIDS. Otherwise that's going to need a longer answer.